# Как вывести из БД строку Money авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: php

Учу php ( *без книг, на практике, базу всю знаю по pascal, а синтаксис по видео понял.*).

Проблема состоит(*возможно*) от не понимания работы команд msql и нормального, четкого и лаконичного объяснения в сети(*не нашел*). 
Хотел бы сделать авторизацию(*она есть*) и дальше пользователь сможет видеть свою виртуальную валюту(в бд она называется money), суть в том, чтобы по клику прибавлять по (0.5) к его числу(*в бд и на экран*). вот что у меня получилось, хотелось бы помощи в данной загвостке=) (*сижу 4 день уже в этом*)

код:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> MONE</title>

</head>
<body>
<center> <h1 class="pink">MONE</h1>

  <div class="Aut">
 <form action="" method="POST">
     <h2>Авторизация</h2>


<p>Логин: <input type="label"  name="username" maxlength="25" class="login" placeholder="  Ваш логин"  required></p>

<p>Пароль:<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" placeholder="   Ваш пароль" required></p>

<input type="submit" class="buttond" name="submitLogin" value=" Авторизация ">
</form>
</div>
<?php

require('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$vkid = $_POST['vkid']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];     

$query= "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' ";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die (msqli_error($msqli));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);




if ($count ==1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

} else {
$fmsg = "ERROR";
 }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
 echo '<style> .Aut {color:black; display:none;} </style>';
echo "<center><div class='hello'><p>Здраствуйте сэр ".$username."  Добро пожаловать! <a href='logout.php' class='logout'> Выход</a></p></div></center>";
echo "<style>.farm {color:white; display:block; width: 100%;} </style>";


}


?>



<p class="buttond"  style="text-align:center;"><a  target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:23px;  text-decoration: none; padding:10px 35px; color:#fcfcfc; background-color:#7032c7; border-radius:36px; border: 3px solid #71048c;" href="/DownVK.php" >Задания</a></p>


<a class="back" href="index.php"> Назад </a>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT money FROM users WHERE username='$username'
Практически тоже самое, если есть значение в таблице money то выведет результат. если там допустим было 1$ при клике как ты говоришь добавляется 0,5 выводишь 1,5$ И Обновляешь значение в таблице

```
 > UPDATE <table> SET <field>='<value>' WHERE <conditions>
```

- где table — имя таблицы; field — поле, для которого будем менять значение; value — новое значение; conditions — условие (без него делать update опасно — можно заменить все данные во всей таблице).

Comment: А можно полный код? просто у меня изначально нет получения из бд MONEY и отправки, а вы указали один запрос всего, я бы хотел еще и понять как и что) и там табилца в бд. а как сделать так, чтобы выводить именно "Ваш баланс:".$money." денег";?)

У меня мой код на показ Валюты с БД не работает

Comment: А можно полный код? просто у меня изначально нет получения из бд MONEY и отправки, а вы указали один запрос всего, я бы хотел еще и понять как и что) и там табилца в бд. а как сделать так, чтобы выводить именно "Ваш баланс:".$money." денег";?)

У меня мой код на показ Валюты с БД не работает.

Как указать поле Filed, если я  не знаю его? ( не знаю id пользователя авторизованного, и не знаю как указывать на автомате